# How to use CXCallObserver in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I need to subscribe an event to handle incoming phone call. Since iOS version 11.0 CTCallCenter is deprecated we have to use CXCallObserver. I successfully implemented solution for CTCallCenter, but I am not able to subscribe event for CXCallObserver. Does anyone have working solution for CXCallObserver?

Here is my code to subscribe event for CTCallCenter..

```
_callCenter = new CTCallCenter();
_callCenter.CallEventHandler += CallEvent;

private void CallEvent(CTCall call)
{
    CoreFoundation.DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchSync(() =>
    {
        if(call.CallState.Equals(call.StateIncoming))
            //Do something
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the delegate for `CXCallObserver`:

```
public class MyCXCallObserverDelegate : CXCallObserverDelegate
{
    public override void CallChanged(CXCallObserver callObserver, CXCall call)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(call);
    }
}
```

Then in your code, create a instance of `CXCallObserver` (maintain a strong reference to this) and then assign the delegate:

```
cXCallObserver = new CXCallObserver();
cXCallObserver.SetDelegate(new MyCXCallObserverDelegate(), null);
```

Comment: Do you also know how to properly release resources of this delegate?

Comment: @JanNepraš There is no weak delegate for `CXCallObserverDelegate`, so personally I keep a reference to both the `CXCallObserver` and `CXCallObserverDelegate` instances, and `Dispose` of them both manually.